# Silverlight - how to auto begin a Storyboard inside a <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I'm trying to display a list of bound data in a  then get a Canvas to animate behind each row.  I'm having trouble getting a Storyboard to Begin when I place it inside a template.  Here is an example of the XAML I have so far:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" Background="Transparent" Foreground="White" Height="200" Width="400" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="MySingleDataTemplate">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="MySingleStackPanel" Margin="0">
                    <StackPanel.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Name="MySingleStoryboard" BeginTime="0:0:1">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames  Storyboard.TargetName="Canvas99" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" 
                                            AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="0" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
                                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="400" KeyTime="0:0:3" />
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </StackPanel.Resources>
                    <Grid Background="Black" x:Name="MySingleGrid" Margin="0" ShowGridLines="False">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col0" Width="300" />
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col1" Width="100" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30" x:Name="Row0" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Canvas Background="{Binding CanvasColour}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="Canvas99" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Field1}" Margin="0"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Field2}" Margin="0"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

How can I call the equivalent of the C#:

```
MySingleStoryboard.Begin();
```

Is there a way I can get it to start from C# or are there some other properties or Triggers I can use in Silverlight?  Or am I going about it in completely the wrong way?

thankyou
Mike

Answer (score 3):

Managed to answer my own question!  I need to add  to my StackPanel, like this:

```
                    <StackPanel.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="StackPanel.Loaded">
                            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard x:Name="MySingleStoryboard" BeginTime="0:0:1">
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames  Storyboard.TargetName="Canvas99" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" 
                                            AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="0" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="400" KeyTime="0:0:3" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger.Actions>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </StackPanel.Triggers>
```

Works a treat, now I just need to get rid of all the margins/boarders etc on the listbox and I'll be happy.... for now.
Mike